# How to get supersets in R?

Tags: r, set, apriori

```
rules <- apriori(table2, parameter = list(minlen=1, sup=s))
itemsets <- unique(generatingItemsets(rules))
itemsets.df <- as(itemsets, "data.frame")
F <- as.matrix(itemsets.df[with(itemsets.df, order(-support,items)),])
```

Output:

```
# items            support
"{a,b}"              "1.0"  
"{a}"                "1.0"  
"{b}"                "1.0"  
"{c,a,b}"            "0.5"  
"{c,a}"              "0.5"  
"{c,b}"              "0.5"  
"{a,b,d}"            "0.5"  
"{a,d}"              "0.5"  
"{b,d}"              "0.5"
```

Using apriori and generatingItemsets to get frequent event sets as shown in "items". But I want only supersets in output i.e. "{c,a,b}" and "{a,b,d}" in this case. What can I do to get supersets only in R?

Comment: You should try to make your examples reproducible. The function apriori and generatingItemsets are unavailable in base R.

Answer (score 2):

If you sort the itemsets (and remove the curly brackets),
the sets you want to remove are prefixes of the next ones.

```
# Sample data
library(arules)
example(apriori)
itemsets <- unique(generatingItemsets(rules))
itemsets.df <- as(itemsets, "data.frame")
F <- as.matrix(itemsets.df[with(itemsets.df, order(-support,items)),])

library(stringr) 
x <- as.character(F[,1])
x <- sort( str_replace_all( x, "[{}]", "" ) )
x
i <- seq_len( length(x) - 1 )
to_remove <- str_detect(x[i+1], paste0("^", x[i]))
x[ ! to_remove ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but it is the first hit on google regarding supersets from apriori rules which I researched for quite some time before finding a quite simple solution using the is.maximal function from the arules package.

So for the question at hand, right after you generate your rules, subset them using is.maximal:

```
rules <- apriori(table2, parameter = list(minlen=1, sup=s))
maximal_rules <- rules[is.maximal(rules)]
```

Then you can grab just the unique itemsets if you'd like:

```
itemsets <- unique(generatingItemsets(maximal_rules))
```

---

Here is a reproducible example using the example data from Vincent's answer:

```
library(arules)
example(apriori)
inspect(rules)
maximal_rules<-rules[is.maximal(rules)]
inspect(maximal_rules)
itemsets <- unique(generatingItemsets(maximal_rules))
inspect(itemsets)
```